# Java nested regular expression groups not capturing inner groups

Tags: java

Why is this regex not capturing the innermost group?

```
final String regex = "s(tra(nsformer))";
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher match = pattern.matcher("stransformer");

if (match.matches()) {
    System.out.println(match.groupCount());
    for (int i = 0; i < match.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println(match.group(i));
    }
}
```

The above returns (in jdk7)

> 2
>
> stransformer
>
> transformer

Oddly enough, `"s(tra((nsformer)))"` pattern works as intended. So does `"s(tra(<inner>nsformer))"`, when I refer to the match as `group("inner")`

What are we missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group count start at index 1. Index 0 contains the entire pattern.
From the javadoc for `group(int)`:

> Capturing groups are indexed from left to right, starting at one.
>   Group zero denotes the entire pattern, so the expression m.group(0) is
>   equivalent to m.group().

So make sure the loop iterates one more step, change the `<` to `<=` for example.

[Matcher.group(int) javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group-int-)

That also explains why it works when adding an extra capturing group, the count increases and you get one of the two innermost but not the last one.
Naming the capturing group works for obvious reasons (nothing was wrong, just listing them was wrong).

Answer (score 1):

Group count goes from 1 to N. As per [`Matcher.groupCount()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#groupCount()) javadoc:

> Group zero denotes the entire pattern by convention. It is not included in this count.

so the code should be:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= match.groupCount(); i++) {
    System.out.println(match.group(i));
}
```

which prints:

```
stransformer
transformer
nsformer
```

Comment: Sorry am able to pick only one as the right answer :\ Thanks for the answer!